# Raphael.js Why are these circles becoming out of phase with time?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to make an infinite animation that depends on a few parameters, it should look more or less like a "radar". The problem is that the circles become out of sync with time and I can't figure out why:

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 800, 800);

var circle = paper.circle(70, 650, 0).attr({
    "stroke-width": 6,
    "fill": "#fff",
    "fill-opacity": 0,
    "stroke": "#D14136"
}).transform("m2, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0");

var circles = paper.set();

function animateRadar(n, speed) {
    // Prepare animation
    var animation = Raphael.animation({
        "r": 50,
        "opacity": 0
    }, speed, function() {

    }).repeat(Infinity);

    // Prepare set
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++  ) {
        circles.push(circle.clone().animate(animation.delay(i * speed/n)));
    }

}

animateRadar(3, 1e3);
```

**[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/D8jNv/)**

Can anyone help me so that every animation is equal to the first one, without the phases becoming out of sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it goes out of sync is `animation.delay(i * speed/n)`. The delay takes place in each `.repeat(Infinity)`, not just in the first as you might expect.

It can be fixed using `setTimeout` instead of `animation.delay`:

```
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 800, 800);

var circle = paper.circle(70, 650, 0).attr({
    "stroke-width": 6,
    "fill": "#fff",
    "fill-opacity": 0,
    "stroke": "#D14136"
}).transform("m2, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0");

var circles = paper.set();

function animateRadar(n, speed) {
    // Prepare animation
    var animation = Raphael.animation({
        "r": 50,
        "opacity": 0
    }, speed, function() {

    }).repeat(Infinity);

    // Prepare set
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++  ) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            circles.push(circle.clone().animate(animation));
        }, i * speed/n);
    }
}

animateRadar(3, 1e3);
```

**[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/D8jNv/)**